# C# - Assembly with code in global namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, .net-assembly

I am referencing an assembly in a project. Is there a way to put everything in the assembly into a namespace?

Right now everything in it is in the global namespace so it makes accessing things weird.

Comment: You can assign alias to assembly reference. Look for `extern alias` for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from the comment @PetSerAl made I found [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/28/extern-alias-walkthrough.aspx) that helped a lot. You can change what the alias is in the references properties and then in the file you want to use something from that assembly you put `extern alias <alias>`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this may be to use a [namespace alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx).

Here is an example:

```
using nsAlias = System.Some.Long.Namespace;

namespace System
{
    class TestClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Using the alias:
            nsAlias.SomeObject test = new nsAlias.SomeObject();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good to know. Although in my case its in the global namespace so it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! For some reason I missed that before.